# Bootstrap 3 - carousel with page numbers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am wondering how to show page numbers with Bootstrap Carousel. Bootstrap has carousel indicators (dot points):

[image]

Is it possible to change the indicator to something like "Page 1/3"?

I have tried adding the number to bootstrap caption and moving it to the left side:

[image]

However, whenever I clicked next, the number didn't stay at its place. Any ideas how to make this better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a working solution:

```
var total = $('.item').length;
var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
$('#slidetext').html(currentIndex + '/'  + total);

// This triggers after each slide change
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;

  // Now display this wherever you want
  var text = currentIndex + '/' + total;
  $('#slidetext').html(text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9krnsm/

Comment: It seems like the `carouselData.getActiveIndex();` is not working anymore. I've made some changes so it's working now http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9krnsm/

Answer (score 0):

```
carousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {

  var active = $(event.target).find('.carousel-inner > .item.active');
  var from = active.index();
  var next = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var to = next.index();
  var direction = event.direction;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5:**

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#client" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
    <li data-target="#client" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
    <li data-target="#client" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
</ol>
```

**SASS:**

```
.carousel-indicators{           
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 80%;

    li{
       width: 17px;
       height: 17px;
       margin: 3px;
       text-indent: 0;
       background-color: $wcolor;
       border: 1px solid $bcolor;
       border-radius: 0;
       line-height: 13px;
      }

      .active {
        width: 17px;
        height: 17px;
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
}
```

[image: Output]